# Get content from distant URL and test

Tags: php, html, get

I have to get data from a .html file, into a distant server. With file_gets_content I can retrieve the informations but when I want to test it I have some problems.

For example I can have 0 or 1 into my .html page. In my .php I want to do something if the file_gets_content return 0 or 1 but for now I didn't find how I can do it

Here is my .html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    0
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP code :

```
$home = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.XXX/wordpress/read.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this php library https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser

```
$dom =HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('http://192.168.1.XXX/wordpress/read.html');

$bodyText=$dom->find("body",0)->innertext;
```

alternative solution is

```
$home = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.XXX/wordpress/read.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($home);
if(($body=$dom->getElementsByTagName("body"))->length>0){
    $text=$body[0]->nodeValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but any solutions like this without using external lib ?

Comment: @Nathan30 You can use the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.